# Firebase Analytics is not available

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xcode7, firebase-analytics

I did a manually install of the `Firebase SDK` to my iOS project. Following the instruction from `README.md`
I included all the files from the Analytics folder:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.framework
FirebaseInstanceID.framework
GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework
GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
GoogleUtilities.framework
```

And I included "`import FirebaseAnalytics`" to my `AppDelegate`. and then I called:

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

But Xcode is still telling me this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '[FIRApp configure] Firebase Analytics is not available.'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104178d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106761deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104178cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   helloworld                              0x0000000103f17190 -[FIRApp configureCore] + 325
    4   helloworld                              0x0000000103f16bb1 +[FIRApp addAppToAppDictionary:] + 100
    5   helloworld                              0x0000000103f162e2 +[FIRApp configureDefaultAppWithOptions:sendingNotifications:] + 268
    6   helloworld                              0x0000000103f16027 +[FIRApp configure] + 302
    7   helloworld                              0x0000000103ee9d81 _TFC6mognet11AppDelegate11applicationfTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPs9AnyObject____Sb + 97
    8   helloworld                              0x0000000103ee9ea4 _TToFC6mognet11AppDelegate11applicationfTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPs9AnyObject____Sb + 180
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001051a49ac -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001051a5c0d -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3415
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001051ac568 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1769
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001051a9714 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    13  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001091bd8c8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001091bd741 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001091bdaca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010409e301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010409422c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040936e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040930f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001051a8f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001051adf09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    22  helloworld                              0x0000000103eea832 main + 114
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010722592d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

What am I doing wrong here? FYI. I am running Xcode Version 7.3.1 and I have the latest SDK.

Comment: better use pod install

Comment: I actually tried pod install first. But the problem was always "0 dependencies installed" whenever I tried.

Comment: Did you get solution of this problem? i am also facing this issue.. please let me know how u fixed this..

Comment: No I didn't. But I think I kind of have an answer for this kind of problem. There might be some issues caused by other services such as Ruby, activesupport, or even cocoapods itself. I don't know which one. So update all of them, which is basically re-install all of them to the latest version. And when I did that, I don't get the warning anymore.

I don't remember the console command for the installs. But if nothing works, this might be the last resort I guess.

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you running?

Comment: Make sure to add all the framework required, then add GoogleService-Info.plist (download it form firebase console) and set other linker flag to -ObjC. Then don't forget to call [FIRApp configure] method - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {... }

Comment: I was running on Swift 3. But after so many tries, I just gave up. And I went to make my entire backend with a freshly configured LAMP environment.

Answer (score 5):

Did you add the -ObjC flag in "Other Linking Flags" setting? When I did this in my Objective-C project, the app stopped crashing when trying to load Firebase. I also included all the Firebase files, used the Firebase.h header and [FIRApp configure] to call Firebase.

I am running Xcode 8.

Comment: Yes and yes I did. But Xcode is still shouting at me as ususal.

Comment: Do you just have the analytics? I have the Firebase analytics and the Admob files.

Comment: Nono, I have the whole SDK with...like everything, AdMob, Analytics, Auth, etc. Then I tried the installing Firebase through making a pod file, pretty much the same way as Google recommend. It works. But if I just drag and drop (manual install) the SDK into my Xcode project, it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: @Giraffe Make sure to add all the framework required, then add GoogleService-Info.plist (download it form firebase console) and set other linker flag to -ObjC. Then don't forget to call [FIRApp configure] method - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {... }